# Creating parent and child object at the same time with External API

Tags: api, odoo, odoo-12, odoo-13

I am using External API to add data to the res.partner model. But I stuck in one point.

Is it possible to create a parent person and contact person (child) at the same time?

If yes, any guidance would be really helpful, as I have not found so much on the internet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to create parent and child contacts same time, let's say in the controller function you have two `dict` containing values for child contact and parent contact (In Odoo concept parent contact is a company and child contacts are the contact persons for that company) for example, `parent_vals` and `child_vals`, you can create the contacts while keeping the relationship by following:

```
self.env['res.partner'].create(dict(parent_vals, child_ids=[(0,0, child_vals)]))
```

How it works is that whenever you want to create a record with related values `(One2many, Many2many)` you can use Odoo ORM special commands. For more information you can lookup 'special “commands”' in Odoo [official documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#create-update),